# Angular Routing Component Testing

Tags: jasmine, angular-test

I am reading the official examples of angular routing testing from [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#routing-component) . I didn't understand how `heroClick()` does trigger click.

```
it('should tell ROUTER to navigate when hero clicked', () => {
  heroClick(); <------- how does this work !?  // trigger click on first inner <div class="hero">

  // args passed to router.navigateByUrl() spy
  const spy = router.navigateByUrl as jasmine.Spy;
  const navArgs = spy.calls.first().args[0];

  // expecting to navigate to id of the component's first hero
  const id = comp.heroes[0].id;
  expect(navArgs).toBe('/heroes/' + id, 'should nav to HeroDetail for first hero');
});
```

Here is a [link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qlbpelxmdqe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard.component.spec.ts) to the stackblitz example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`heroClick` is a parameter passed to the `tests()` function in line 84. It's a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing. On line 120, `heroClick()` calls whatever was passed to `tests()`.

On lines 27 and 48 `tests()` is called, passing different functions `clickForShallow` and `clickForDeep`, defined just below their usages. Those function simulate the clicks by interacting with the elements in the component.

Comment: Do you mean passing function that takes no arguments and returns nothing will trigger the clicks ?

Comment: No, passing a function is just like passing any other value. But line 120 calls the function passed as an argument. I've edited the answer to clarify that.